# How to keep certain columns when filtering dataframe by regex

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am preforming a filter on columns containing `tweet_volume` using regex, by the following command:

`tweet_volume_df = df_merged.filter(regex=("tweet_volume.*"))`

Within `df_merged` there is a column for `name`.  I would like to include columns `name` in `tweet_volume_df`.

How do I perform this operation in a single line?

Answer (score 2):

You can do with

```
df.filter(regex=r'(Name|tweet_volume.*)',axis=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use "|" in the regular expression, to match name or tweet_volume.*:

```
import pandas as pd

data = [list(range(5))]
headers = ['name', 'tweet_volume1', 'tweet_volume2', 'a', 'b']
df_merged = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=headers)

tweet_volume_df = df_merged.filter(regex=("tweet_volume.*|name"))
```